# Azure VM monitoring

Tags: azure, monitoring, virtualization

I want to prepare a report about monitoring Windows Azure Virtual Machines programmatically. Is there any such API?

I'd like to monitor VMs based on memory/CPU usage, communcations among VMs, VM subscription details etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System Center 2012 Service Pack 1 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34607) which has built in monitoring for Azure VMs.

There are two downsides to SCOM.  First, it is not free (although it may be provided at no cost to your company if they have a good enough EA with Microsoft).  Second, there is a fairly steep learning curve to get SCOM up and running in your environment.

Regardless, SCOM will do everything you are asking about and much, much more.  You might want to check out the 30-day trial and see if it is something you want to pursue further.

To get started, check out [How to monitor your Windows Azure application with System Center 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dcaro/archive/2012/05/02/how-to-monitor-your-windows-azure-application-with-system-center-2012.aspx).

Comment: Dear Robert Greiner, Thanks a lot for your response.Could you please let me know whether there is any site/link for azure vm monitoring using system center?

Comment: Thanks Robert,but this link explains about how Azure application can be monitored but not how Azure VMs can be monitored....it seems that SC-VMM can be connected to SC-OM to monitor the health and availability of the virtual machines and virtual machine hosts that VMM manages.Does VMM manage Azure VMs also?Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Robert is correct, it is not recommended. Please review [Considerations for server-side automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) before you proceed.